# Django 2.x filter and sort calculated boolean field

Tags: django

I am trying to figure out how to enable sorting by a calculated boolean field. I have seen some other related posts, but I cannot figure them out. I tried to add a custom manager for Files, but it did not work. I want to be able to sort and filter values according to calculated fields like `exists`.

```
class File(models.Model):
    archive = models.ForeignKey("Archive", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=2000, unique=False, validators=[validate_is_file])
    comment = RichTextField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return basename(self.file_name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.title = basename(self.file_name)
        super(File, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def preview(self):
        return bs4(self.comment).get_text()

    def exists(self):
        return isfile(self.file_name)
    exists.boolean = True

    def size(self):
        return getsize(self.file_name)

    def created(self):
        return convert_ctime(time.ctime(getctime(self.file_name)))

    def modified(self):
        return convert_ctime(time.ctime(getmtime(self.file_name)))



class FileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['file_name', 'archive']
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'style': 'width: 90%;'})},
        }

    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['title', 'comment', 'file_name', 'archive']})
        ] 
    list_display = ['exists', 'file_name', 'size', 'created', 'modified', 'title', 'preview',]
    search_fields = ['title', 'file_name', 'comment', 'created', 'modified']
    list_filter = ['exists']  # This does not work


admin.site.register(Archive, ArchiveAdmin)
admin.site.register(File, FileAdmin)
```

Comment: from where the function **`isfile()`** comes?

Comment: `os.path.isfile`

Comment: the **`list_filter`** magic usually works in the database level, whereas in your case it supposed to be work on the code level.